# CSS Text Highlight with Irregular Borders

Tags: css, canvas

I'm trying to highlight text on a page with a **non-rectangular background** (i.e. a highlight where the border uses jaunty angles).  The text is fluid (i.e. it flows in the space available ).

[irregularly shaped highlight http://mockupserver.com/irregular_example.png](http://mockupserver.com/irregular_example.png)

I've been searching the web and wracking my brain trying to think of a solution; possibly something using the canvas element.  This is a non-critical design element; if it only worked in the most modern browsers and showed rectangular borders in older browsers; that would be quite satisfactory.

Anyone have any ideas?

**Update**:
As per suggestions below; I tried using the border-image style attributes to create the effect.  I started by putting my text in a *SPAN* (rather than, say, a *P*, which would draw a rectangular box around the text block - rather than a border around each individual line).  I then tried using style attributes like the following:

```
-moz-border-image:url("border.png") 5% stretch stretch;
-webkit-border-image:url("border.png") 5% stretch stretch;
border-image:url("border.png") 5% stretch stretch;
```

Which very nearly works... except that I get radically different results in different browsers.  For example; in Chrome the border image gets stretched once across all lines of text (i.e. the left side of the image starts at the beginning of the first line, and the right side of the image ends at the end of the last line); whereas in FF it gets stretched across each line once (i.e. on each line the image begins and ends).

Also; the design calls for each line of text to have different angles to the lines; which isn't an option in any of the browsers.

Comment: To be clear, you don't want this during selection ('highlight'); you want these background shapes to be always visible, right?

Comment: That is correct.  The dark colour in the image is meant to be a background to the text; not how the text would appear if it is selected.  The designer has added a few elements to the design that are meant to convey a hand crafted look; one of which is this irregular text background.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done. BUT ! You could use PHP to generate some kind of non-rectangular form with pre-defined image.

Answer (score 0):

If you have CSS3 capabilities, border-image might be an option. Set the border image to your jaunty edges setup with a background color/image the same as the border so it blends nicely. I've posted a link below. I haven't used border-image before, but it seems a possibility from what I've read [here](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/).

Comment: Your suggestion comes very close to solving my issue.